# DJango 2 db routing

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

в Django2 есть два проекта с одинаковыми моделями, как реализовать авторизацию в первом проекте из базы второго проекта

БД - postgreSQL

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Фраза "реализовать авторизацию" охватывает очень много и не ясно, что именно вам нужно. Не ясно вопрос именно про использование двух БД, т.е. о том, как модели одного django appliction хранить в одной БД, а другого(их) в другой БД (т.е. чисто про routing)? Или все же это имеет отношение к собственно авторизации. Отредактируйте вопрос, чтоб учесть эти моменты. В текущем виде, на вопрос не ответить.